# Find an N satisfying this inequality

Tags: sequences-and-series, inequality

I am trying to catch up again.
$$
\frac{1}{2^{n}} + \frac{1}{3^{n}} + \frac{1}{4^{n}} < \frac{1}{365}
$$
Find an $N$ whereby all $n \geq N$ give correct outcomes

I thought that as long as $\frac{1}{2^{n}} < \frac{1}{365}$ is small enough, the addition of both the others won't matter.
So $n=9$, so $1/512 + \dots$

Comment: You might want to give http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10647/how-do-i-write-a-good-title/10648#10648 a read. Although it was written for Stack Overflow, the points still apply. From that question title, we have *zero* idea what the actual problem is.

Comment: Usually, I correct the misspelled latex when I see it. Here, I don't know what your formulas are supposed to mean. What is expt, for example? Please see http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference and edit your question, else nobody will understand what you are asking.

Comment: The latex is not correct. It is just 2 exponent -n, and for 3 and 4. or 1/(2 power n).

Comment: Every `1/k^{-n}` should read `1/k^n` or `k^{-n}`.

Comment: @Ignace Since it is *your* question, please, correct the latex instead of just complaining it is wrong.

Comment: The thing is decreasing. If calculator is allowed, and even if it is not, compute a bit. Your guess is reasonable, but it can be verified.

Comment: I'll try, ok ...

Comment: It's ok as it looks now.

Answer (score 2):

I really don't understand the downvotes and hostility towards the OP in the comments, so I'll just answer to make up for the nastiness.

As it happens, $n = 9$ will do (just check it), but if you want to avoid calculation, we can get a crude bound as follows.

You want some $n$ such that $$\frac1{2^n} + \frac1{3^n} + \frac1{4^n} < \frac1{365}.$$
Of the three terms, the first is the biggest: in other words, we can bound the other two by the first term:
$$\frac{1}{3^n} < \frac1{2^n}$$
$$\frac{1}{4^n} < \frac1{2^n}$$
so
$$\frac{1}{2^n} + \frac{1}{3^n} + \frac{1}{4^n} < \frac{1}{2^n} + \frac{1}{2^n} + \frac{1}{2^n} = \frac{3}{2^n}$$

So it is enough to find an $n$ such that $$\frac{3}{2^n} < \frac1{365},$$
which is equivalent to
$$\frac{1}{2^n} < \frac{1}{3 \times 365} = \frac{1}{1095}$$
which is the same as
$$2^n > 1095.$$

So $n = 11$ (or any larger $n$) will do. (It turns out that $n=9$ will do, but this requires slightly more calculation.)